# Использование разных языков в приложении android studio

Tags: android, локализация

У меня есть `activity` и в нем 2 кнопки.

1. Русский язык
2. Казахский язык

При нажатии на кнопки должна открываться другая `activity` с выбранном языком. У меня `Activity` открывается, но язык не меняется.

В гугле поискал, ничего подобного не нашел.

Comment: По-моему, в андроиде язык будет выбран в соответсвии с тем какой используется в вашем устройстве. Попробуйте сменить язык и нажать еще раз.

Comment: Нет, мне надо изменить язык приложения

Например нажал на русский язык, открывается русский интерфейс, 
нажал на казахский, открывается казахский интерфейс

Comment: Я так понял базовая активность должна остаться с языком системы?

Answer (score 1):

Программно менять язык в андроиде не рекомендуется.

```
 Resources res = context.getResources();
 DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
 android.content.res.Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
 conf.locale = new Locale(language_code.toLowerCase()); // вроде бы kk_KZ для казахстана
 res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот так я меняю язык у себя в приложении

```
public void setLocale(String lang) {
    myLocale = new Locale(lang);
    Resources res = getResources();
    DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
    Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
    conf.locale = myLocale;
    res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
    Intent refresh = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(refresh);
}
```

После смены локали нужно рестартронуть `activity`

Answer (score 0):

В коде Activity нужно прописать:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Configuration configuration = getResources().getConfiguration();
    configuration.locale = new Locale("ru");
    getResources().updateConfiguration(configuration, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

    // для применения смены локали к заголовку
    setTitle(R.string.activity_title);

    // далее создаем layout
}
```

Так в каждой отдельной активити можно использовать свой язык. Но так делать не рекомендуется.

Comment: Это где прописать?
В каждом Activity?

Comment: @Andrei да, в каждом активити, в котором вы хотите использовать язык, отличный от системного. И язык задается параметром `в new Locale("ru");`. В данном случае это русский.

Comment: Помог, но есть что то.
Заголовки не меняются при выборе языка

Comment: Вызови явно setTitle после смены локали